# lsof -i output *:*?

Tags: lsof

What is the meaning of the output under the **NAME** tag of the `lsof -i`
command when it appears as such `*:*`

Example output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `UDP *:*` means you have processes on your system listening on all network interfaces for IPv4 UDP packets:

- All IPv4 Addresses are represented by a `*` on the left of the colon
- All ports are represented by a `*` on the right of the colon

You can test this by sending a batch of 5 UDP packets to one of your local addresses with netcat:

`$ echo "data" | nc -w1 -u 127.0.0.1 1-5`

While using lsof in repeat mode to show the UDP connection activity:

```
$ lsof -r1 -iUDP -P -n  | grep -E "^nc"
nc         3197           root    3u  IPv4 0x614d3be71aa32a89      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57137->127.0.0.1:2
nc         3197           root    3u  IPv4 0x614d3be71b503dc9      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:62455->127.0.0.1:3
nc         3197           root    3u  IPv4 0x614d3be71bdbe351      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:52982->127.0.0.1:4
nc         3197           root    3u  IPv4 0x614d3be71b6335b9      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:61450->127.0.0.1:5
```